# Obtain a text with underline and strikethrough at the same time

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

**For text widget, we may use the text decoration for `strike` or `underline`**

```
style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
```

Is there any way can obtain both in the text decoration? Or is there any solution to do with the Boxdecoration? I have tried but not that succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use combine instade

```
Text(
  "Hello world!",
  style: TextStyle(
    decoration: TextDecoration.combine(
        [TextDecoration.underline, TextDecoration.lineThrough]),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You Need to Add

> Decoration

In your Text Widget For Doing this :
Here is the Example :

```
decoration: TextDecoration.combine(
    [TextDecoration.underline, TextDecoration.lineThrough]),
```

Answer (score 0):

**One possible solution is to use `Container` like this :**

```
       Container(
          child: Text(
            'This text has underline as well as linethrough',
            style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(
                color: const Color(0xFF000000),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

**Output :**

[image]